# How to pop up the window screen created using tkinter in the middle of the screen

Tags: python, tkinter

How to popup the tkinter created window in the middle of the screen

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry("200x200")
Label(window,text="Hello World").grid(row=0,column=0,sticky = W)
window.mainloop()
```

Check for the answer below

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know the basics of tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry("200x200")
Label(window,text="Hello World").grid(row=0,column=0,skicky = W)
window.mainloop()
```

This will create a basic tkinter window with a label at 0,0 with geometry 200x200 .

But the problem here is the window will pop up at the random places in the screen ,You cannot peronally tell where to popup,if you want to give co-ordinates to the screen you can give using below line

```
window.geometry("200x200+100+100")
```

will popup a window with geometry 200x200 at x co-ordinate 100 and y co-cordinate.
If you share your code with other people,the resolution of your screen may be different and others' screen maybe different .So how to find out a way to get in the middle always.

There is a solution.

Tkinter has a function which will grab the width and height of the screen

```
window.winfo_screenwidth()
window.winfo_screenheight()
```

Now you can use the below formula to make sure that screen pops up in the middle screen

```
window_width = 200
window_height = 200
x = int(int(window.winfo_screenwidth()/2) - int(window_width/2))
y = int(int(window.winfo_screenheight()/2) - int(window_height/2))
window.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")
```

Comment: You know that you can use `window.winfo_width()` and `window.winfo_height()` instead of your `window_width` and `window_height` variables

Comment: `window_width`  and `window_height` are width and height of the application

Comment: It is much easier to just use `window.winfo_width()` and `window.winfo_height()` especially if you don't know the size of the new window.

Comment: You got it wrong ,I knew that my window would be `200x200` ,So I took two variables

Comment: I am guessing that you wrote this answer for other people that are experiencing this problem. Therefore, you can't assume that they know the size of the window. When using `window.winfo_width()` it will give you the width at that moment in time even if you haven't set it using `.geometry(...)`